# how to convert unicode and display in browser? reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode

I am creating a messages page where admin and client can send and receive messages and I am getting some characters which show up, and another developer tells me it's unicode.

something like this

```
\u2019hey
```

or this

```
m\u0159i\u0165 sroun\u011br tro\u0161a hro\u010d ti\u010d s\u00fds\u016f v diplych o zrutr\u00fd. Zlyzli crest\u016fstbukl\u00e1 slokab zlecou, a nij \u0159uk\u00fd tiv. Nij dratl\u00e1h. Tref\u00fd zraditi tin\u011bgle. \u017el\u00edzlod mrytl\u00e9 n\u011bj vosk n\u011bmu z chlyv\u011bt oskev ston div\u011bm. Nivp\u00e1du\u0161 obozr\u016f sre\u0165n\u011bch k\u0159oufl\u00fd a pi\u0148 syb\u0159otru slou\u0161\u00ed. Bliti m\u0159opidtisly vuvle obu ji\u0161 p\u0159a\u010d m\u00e1n\u011b chapupotid \u017eredi hl\u00fdt zrouskod. Vl\u016fbu lkyd k mlozrat, brsk mled\u0159ej koudyzrozr\u00e1 \u0161k\u00fdnid k t\u011bviz. Z kluz studip bruh\u0159ou s d\u00e1tiv\u011b ti\u017elo dikre\u010d. Zu veplev \u0148\u00e1mesk \u010fo\u010d k otil. T\u0159a\u010d i tipo vl\u00e9\u0165o\u0165 k su\u010f kl\u00fdpru \u0161udi\u0148\u010fa
```

so, how do I convert it to a format more suitable to display on the browser?? using reactjs

these could be icons or anything . not sure.

Here's an example array of what I am getting from server.
I am putting it into an array and then looping through it to display like this

```
msgContent = arr.map((item,index)=>{
      let len = arr.length-1;
      if(len ===index){
        return <span key={index+100} className={styles.textMsg}>{item}</span>
      }else{
        return <span key={index+100} className={styles.textMsg}>{item}<br/></span>
      }
    })
```

and it still shows up garbled.
could you tell me where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Outputting HTML entities as unicode numbers in JSX [looks like you would expect](https://codesandbox.io/s/3vw4qqrpjp).

Comment: Set encoding as utf-8

Comment: encoding is already utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Different ways of displaying [HTML entities are listed in the documentation](https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#html-entities). The examples you have in your question are unicode numbers corresponding to the entity, which works perfectly fine as strings in JSX, so if you just want to display them properly, you don't have to change it at all.

**Example**

```
function App() {
  return <div> {"\u2019hey"} </div>;
}
```

Comment: updated my answer to show what I am doing. but it seems like I am already doing what you say.

Comment: @faraz Alright. Could you create a reproducible example in e.g. CodeSandbox we can take a look at?

Comment: @faraz Great. You are escaping every  \  by writing  \ \ , it isn't interpreted as HTML entities. Do you have any way of not escaping all your `content`?

Comment: you mean whatever is in this.state.data?? that's what I am receiving from the server

Comment: @faraz Compare the text in your question with the text in your `content`. The text that works just have one slash, e.g. `\u2019hey`. You are escaping every slash with another slash, \ \u2019hey

Comment: but I am not putting any slashes in there at all.
just displaying whatever comes and
\u2019hey . is that supposed to be like this??

Comment: @faraz Yes, but the data that you get is escaped.

Comment: so, I need to unescape that?? i.e. remove the slashes?? how do I do that? and If I could do that. then I dont want to remove slashes that the user types in.

Comment: Yes, I kinda understand now. I removed one slash from \\u2019hey and what displayed was 'hey . So, maybe I need to check for 2 slashes and remove one from the content

Comment: @faraz That might be a good solution. Maybe you can ask your develop colleague to not escape it when he sends it to you as well, but that might not be an option.

Comment: Ah. Yes. I will tell him and see what he says